# Алгоритм для колоды карт

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование

Вопрос. Например у нас есть карты от 9 до туза. 4 масти. Складываем карты по порядку и по масти от 19 до туза: 9 пики, 10 пики, валет пики, дама пики, король пики, туз пики. Далее делаем так со всеми остальными мастями. Складываем по порядку, и сбиваем колоду. Я сбивал 5 раз подряд, но затем раскладываю колоду ( просто достаю по порядку карты), и у меня всегда получается по порядку. Пусть не с самой низкой карты, но по порядку, например: валет, дама, король, туз, десять, девять. В итоге я получаю 4 стопки карт от валета до девятки. Да, масти разные. Необходим алгоритм, как сбить колоду, чтобы получить стопку карт с двумя десятками, например?

Comment: Здесь не все знакомы с карточным сленгом. Что значит "сбить колоду"? Если речь идет о "сдвиге" верхней части колоды и перекладывании ее вниз, то никак, разумеется. "Сдвиг колоды" - это просто циклический сдвиг карт в последовательности. Циклическая последовательность не меняется, циклическое расстояние между картами одинакового достоинства не меняется. Поэтому карты одинакового достоинства всегда будут попадать в разные колоды.

Comment: Вообще нельзя никогда достичь?

Comment: Ну если перекладывать бесконечное время... Бесконечность - она такая. На бесконечности возможно все, %username%...

Comment: А если я скажу, что 717 раз будет достаточно?!  Как опровергнуть мое предположение?

Comment: Показать, что (я цитирую): "Циклическая последовательность не меняется, циклическое расстояние между картами одинакового достоинства не меняется.", т.е. остается равным 6. И сделать из этого вывод: "Поэтому карты одинакового достоинства всегда будут попадать в разные колоды."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы раскладываете колоду из 24 карт на четыре стопки: 6 первых карт в первую, 6 вторых карт во вторую и т.д. При таком раскладе, если две карты в колоде отстоят друг от друга на 6 или более карт, то они заведомо попадут в разные стопки (утверждение 1)

В исходной колоде "десятки" лежат в позициях

```
d, d + 6, d + 12, d + 18           // утверждение 2
```

т.е. соседние "десятки" лежат на расстоянии 6 друг от друга. (В исходной колоде `d` равно 2, но будем продолжать обозначать это значение через `d`).

После того, как мы разделили колоду на две части и поменяли эти части местами, те соседние пары "десяток", которые попали в одну часть, как лежали на расстоянии 6 друг от друга, так и остались лежать на расстоянии 6.

Если все четыре "десятки" попали в одну и ту же часть колоды, то их расположение после обмена частей по-прежнему выражается (2), просто для другого значения `d`.

Если же какие-то "десятки" попали в разные части колоды, то после обмена частей могло измениться только расстояние между "новыми соседями": первой и последней "десяткой" исходной колоды (исходные позиции `d` и `d + 18`). Рассмотрим, что произошло с ними. Независимо от того, в каком месте мы разделили колоду, расстояние между этими "новыми соседями" после обмена частей будет равно

```
(24 - (d + 18)) + d
```

А это снова 6. Это сразу говорит нам о том, что и в этом случае расположение "десяток" в колоде по-прежнему выражается (2), просто для другого значения `d`.

Таким образом, сколько бы мы ни "снимали" колоду, соседние "десятки" в этой колоде будут всегда лежать на расстоянии 6 друг от друга, как указано в (2). Меняться будет лишь значение `d`. А значит, согласно (1), "десятки" после раскладывания всегда будут попадать в разные стопки.